# React firing multiple events on key pressed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React here, and trying to understand what's going with this simple code here:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class MainView extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            role: ''
        };
        this._keyPressed = this.keyPressed.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        const { role } = this.state;

        document.addEventListener("keyup", this._keyPressed.bind(this));

        return (
            <div className="container">
                <input id="role" value={role} type="text"
                   onChange={
                       (newValue) => this.setState({
                           role: newValue.target.value
                       })
                   }
                />
            </div>
        );
    }

    keyPressed(event) {
        console.log(event);
    }
}

if (document.getElementById('mainview')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<MainView />, document.getElementById('mainview'));
}
```

The problem is that whilst pressing random keys on the keyboard result in the expected behaviour, e.g.:

```
KeyboardEvent {isTrusted: true, key: "h", code: "KeyH", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
KeyboardEvent {isTrusted: true, key: "d", code: "KeyD", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
KeyboardEvent {isTrusted: true, key: "g", code: "KeyG", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
```

when adding text to the input box, the KeyboardEvent is fired multiple times, depending on current input lenght. More specifically, the event is fired n times, where n is the actual number of times the input has been modified, counting each added/deleted char, e.g.:

adding "a" char to the input:

```
KeyboardEvent {isTrusted: true, key: "a", code: "KeyA", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
KeyboardEvent {isTrusted: true, key: "a", code: "KeyA", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
```

then adding "v" char:

```
KeyboardEvent {isTrusted: true, key: "v", code: "KeyV", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
KeyboardEvent {isTrusted: true, key: "v", code: "KeyV", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
KeyboardEvent {isTrusted: true, key: "v", code: "KeyV", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
```

deleting last (v) char:

```
KeyboardEvent {isTrusted: true, key: "Backspace", code: "Backspace", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
KeyboardEvent {isTrusted: true, key: "Backspace", code: "Backspace", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
KeyboardEvent {isTrusted: true, key: "Backspace", code: "Backspace", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
KeyboardEvent {isTrusted: true, key: "Backspace", code: "Backspace", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
```

Altough I've managed to realize the existance of a relationship between the KeyboardEvent  event and the onChange event of the input element, I'm a bit confused and I can't figure out correcly how this is really working.

Any explanation whould be really appreciated, thank you.

Comment: it because the component re render everytime you press a key

Comment: Ok fine, but why 4 times in a row? That happens even if i press another key with the input off focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React advise against the use of native event handlers like the one you create using addEventListener.

In general, you should add an event handler to a component only, like you did with onChange.

What happened here is that your onChange listener changes the state each time you enter a character, therefore re-rendering the component. Since you add the listener to keyup in the render function, a new one is added at each rendering.